# Node Js pm2 restarts with now reason

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a pm2 server which, with no apparent reason, restarts every time someone is uploading a file to the server, no matter the size of the file.
I tried increasing the `--max-memory-restart` to 2048M

What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't start your process with `--watch` or using watch in a ecosystem-file? https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/ (Because that will restart your process every time something changes). And if you are watching the entire directory, you might want to change that to specific files or subdirectories.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was de problem, I was making some changes and didn´t know I would restart if I didn´t make a change. Now it´s working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Di you see the logs on the server? With pm2 you can see all the errors in the log file that are happening. Try to review the logs file and try to be more specific next time.

Comment: The problem is I just don´t get an error on log. Only I get is "server listening on port.." so I know server restarted, but get no other reason